# Can't print the value of RGB (pixel)

Tags: python, ubuntu, pixel

Here is the code:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("test.png")
pix = img.load()
(r,g,b) = pix[10,20]
print "R[%d],G[%d],B[%d]" % (r,g,b)
```

It was working fine yesterday. Now if I run it :

```
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    (r,g,b) = pix[10,20]
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I have no idea why it doesn't worked anymore.
Any help would be appreciate.

edit: Solved with : sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-imaging

Comment: `pix[10, 20]` returns an integer instead of an iterator/tuple to assign to x, y, z. Try printing out its value.

Comment: if I print the value of pix[10,20], it's : 0. The fact is that it worked before. I was able to print the RGB value of a selected pixel with this code.

Comment: check `img.shape`. It's perhaps a black and white image.

Comment: I use the same image since the beginning. If I try : img.shape, I get an error: AttributeError: shape

Comment: PNGs can use paletted images. Try converting the image to RGB if you want to get the RGB values of pixels.

Comment: If I convert the image to RGB,, the values of R, G and B are 0 or 1. Instead of for exemple 255